# Get the last tags from git tag --list 'v*'

Tags: bash, git

We have a Repo that contains multiple projects, and therefore we have multiple different tags. For example mobile app tags are in the format of `v1.1.0, v1.2.0` and API tags are in the format of `api-1.1.0, api-1.1.0`.

I want to set up a bash script where I get the latest created tags for a specific project. Now I know that the mobile project tags will always be `v.1.1.0`

So, I have the bash Script:

`git tag --list 'v*'`

Which returns: `v1.1.0 v1.2.0`

However I cant figure out how to select the latest tag created from that list so that the bash command only returns: `v1.2.0`

Comment: use awk: git tag --list 'v*' | awk '{print $NF}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--sort=<key>` attribute to make sure the most recent version comes last, then use `tail` to extract that last line only :

```
git tag --list --sort=version:refname 'v*' | tail -1
```

`--sort=version:refname` (or `--sort=v:refname` for short) treats the tagnames as versions while using them as a sort key as documented in `git tag --help` and is necessary to avoid the default lexicographic sort order.